# php exec mysql empty output

Tags: php, mysql, exec

I try to capture the error output.

```
   <?php
        $output = array();
        $command = <<<END
mysql -h$host -u$user --password='$pass' --execute="create database $name;" 2>&1
END;
        exec($command, $output, $code);
    ?>
```

1. $output returns no value
2. $code returns 0

But this query returns an error in the terminal: "database already exists".

When I remove 2>&1

```
     $command = <<<END
        mysql -h$host -u$user --password='$pass' --execute="create database $name;"
END;
     exec($command, $output, $code);
```

1. $output returns no value
2. $code returns 1

How can I get the correct $output and $code value?

Comment: Any reason for not using [`mysql_create_db()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-create-db.php)?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't suit me. I write my own t_exec() function which executes and captures errors for shell commands.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, except that I was importing a .sql file instead of using --execute

It worked after I added 2>&1 and using double quotes instead of singles.

```
exec("mysql -h $host -u $user -p$pass my_db < \"faulty_sql.sql\" 2>&1",$output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [system()](http://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=php%2bsystem&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php&ei=Q7ezTsP4Nuah4gSg8KTfAw&usg=AFQjCNF2v9VN1wgaH_NBrIkpapJ1qjvYfA)

p.s: why don't use `msyql_query('your query');` ?

Comment: I write my own exec() function which executes and captures errors for shell commands.

Comment: system returns an empty result too